# How to completely delete/uninstall (K)Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu, kubuntu, delete

I am pretty new to ubuntu/linux. I love the linux idea and i was looking for distribution i would choose. I chose Kubuntu 14.04, burned .iso on dvd and installed Kubuntu without problems. Then i was looking inside the OS itself and i didnt liked it. I decided to try Xubuntu 14.04 instead. I searched if it is possible to switch between them.

I tried http://www.linux.org/threads/converting-between-the-ubuntus.5079/ . But some of commands didnt work for me and it was late so i decided to give up and try it next day. But i couldnt shutdown system, i could work with it but couldnt shut it down. So i decided to shut down computer with its shutdown button.

Next day when i chose ubuntu in grub it was loading almost for an hour and did nothing. Is there any way how can i delete/uninstall/repair/switch to Xubuntu from this K/Ubuntu if i dont have access to it? I can acces the root terminal from recovery mode but cant access the OS itself. And also i can access 2 recovery modes in grub: newer version (3.15 or smth like that) or older?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you have a CD / USB with the full ISO of the Ubuntu download on it?

Comment: I have CD with full ISO of Kubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start the computer press shift.

In the grub menu choose recovery mode

In the popup submenu choose in this successive order

```
fsck
network
root
```

Finished the processes you start a terminal

Run it

```
sudo su
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop
apt-get clean
apt-get remove --purge kde* kate k3b konsole kubuntu*
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```

Comment: So i tried it and fsck repaired clock and something else. But network didnt work, it says: ModemManager[994]: <warn> Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:05:00.0'': not supported by any plugin. There are two more similiar to this. I have a pc that is connected to wi-fi. It might be the problem with the device that gets the wi-fi signal (dont know how is it called). But when i was in Kubuntu i had no problem with connecting to internet.

Answer (score 0):

Test this for wifi manual configuration:

First run iwconfig to see if the wireless extensions are enabled.

```
sudo su
iwconfig
```

If you are informed that there is a wifi card, for example wlan0 and wireless interface is recognized as going to:

Second to view the available wireless networks run:

```
sudo su
iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Networks will show your scope and ESSID notes proper ESSID

Third, knowing the ESSID and the network password, run:

```
sudo su
ifconfig wlan0 up
iwconfig wlan0 essid <ESSID>
iwconfig wlan0 key s:password_wireless
```

Fourth, you must request an IP address from the DHCP server, run:

```
sudo su
dhclient wlan0
```

good luck!

Comment: I tried it and it is working fine except to part with iwconfig key. What is the key? I tried the password that i type when i want to connect to network. I tried the original password that was wrote on router, and i even tried other number that was wrote at router but none of them worked. It says something like Invalid argument. How can I solve it? Thank you!